# Remove objects from JS array upto a certain index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
array = [S1,S2,S3,S4_a,S4_b,S5_a,S5_b,S5_c etc....]
```

How can I delete all the objects from the last object down to what ever index I give it ?

array.delte(last:S3)

So, I would like to to delete downto S3, so everything after it must be deleted

```
new_array = [S1,S2,S3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think you want [`splice`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp):

```
array.splice(0, index);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

a = a.splice(0, 3);
// a is now [1, 2, 3]
```

or, if you don't know the position of `3`:

```
a = a.splice(0, a.indexOf(3) + 1);
```

Be aware though, that some browsers do not implement `Array.indexOf` so consider using a library such as jQuery or prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript
array splice function , or array slice function. see  : http://jsfiddle.net/

```
var origArray = new Array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g');
var myIndex = 4;
var origArray = origArray.slice(0,myIndex);  // is now ['a','b','c','d']
```

Comment: Ok, but this will return the removed array, I want the array without the removed objects.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all after index:

```
var index=3;
var arr1=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];
arr1.length=index; // now arr1 contains ['a','b','c']
```

Deleting all before index:

```
var index=3;
var arr1=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];
var arr2=arr1.slice(index); // now arr2 contains ['d','e','f','g']; arr1 remains unchanged
```